# Update Server JDK and JRE after Oracle Database Installation and creation

Tags: linux, oracle-12c, installation, java

Will there be any impact on existing Oracle Database if we upgrade the server JDK/JRE versions in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Database ships with its own JDK, it does not use the JDK you install on Linux.

So you can upgrade that without any impact.